# How to Reduce Size of .NET 6 Self-Contained Linux Executable with MongoDB.Driver?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mongodb

I'm working on creating a lightweight executable for Linux using **.NET 6**. Here are my requirements:

- **Avoid AOT**.
- Must be **self-contained**.
- Include the **MongoDB.Driver** NuGet package.

I've configured my publish profile with these flags:

```xml
<SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
```

However, the resulting sizes of my files are:

```
-a---          09.05.2023    15:05       12371960 libmongocrypt.so
-a---          30.10.2023    17:29       21282427 Veeam.MongoDB.Broker
```

Is there a way I can further reduce the size of my executable? Any guidance or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In my experience self contained files are never small.  They must contain all of the framework components that you used.  Make sure you don't have any extra usings or references that you don't need.  That is also a very small file compared to what I have seen on windows self contained single exes

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change size of the mongo package

Comment: Linux `strip` command makes the binary 1/3 of the original size, but then it fails to start.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid AOT, for a smaller size using PublishReadyToRun would be helpful

Comment: It's not compatible with the code we're using:( It's not ready to be used with tons of obsolete code, reflection, etc...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not possible to make it smaller. And even this produces a library that is broken. `MongoDB.Driver` is not trim compatible and will break if you try to trim it.

You can try using various flags described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options?pivots=dotnet-6-0#trimming-framework-library-features , but they don't make a big difference.